# Javascript string casting problem

Tags: javascript

Something wierd is happening in my javascript and i dont understand it. Can anyone explain?

```
var adsl2pSpeed = '9500 - 12500';

        alert(adsl2pSpeed);

        if (!adsl2pSpeed) {
            alert(adsl2pSpeed);
            var adsl2pSpeed = 'Unknown';
        }


        var speed = document.getElementById("PredictedSpeed");
        speed.innerHTML = adsl2pSpeed + " b/s";
```

This alerts "Undefined" twice and sets the innerhtml to be "Unknown". If I comment out the if statment it alerts '9500 - 12500' and sets the innerHTML to be '9500 - 12500'. Whats happening? Is the string is being cast as an object so it becomes null?

**EDIT** : I am actually registing the adsl2pSpeed  as a startup script not in the function. I moved it up for clarity but possibly that is the problem?

Comment: Testcase please. Looking at the indentation the real code has stuff between the first two lines...

Comment: Is that  your exact code? Or is something in a function?

Comment: something else is going on. This fiddle works ok... http://jsfiddle.net/2jz9k/ What browser are you using? What is your markup? Do you have any funky libraries loaded etc...?

Comment: Doesn't for me: http://jsfiddle.net/v6D9r/. Show us the rest of the code. BTW, you don't need the `var` before `var adsl2pSpeed = 'Unknown';`... the variable adsl2pSpeed has already been declared.

Comment: @Matt: I think that `var` is causing the problem because the indented code is in its own function (which Tom did not tell us about), and the `var` makes a new local variable.

Comment: @Thilo: Impressive thinking outside the box if that's the case :P :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speculation:

The indented code is in a function.

```
   if (!adsl2pSpeed) {
        alert(adsl2pSpeed);
        var adsl2pSpeed = 'Unknown';
    }
```

You are in that function declaring a local variable, which masks the global variable, so it looks "undefined".

Try to remove the `var` to avoid making a new variable.

Comment: +1 Would seem like that's the most obvious cause. Would help if the OP mentioned that (if that is indeed the case...)

Answer (score 0):

I think Thilo is right.
If the code is in a function like:

```
var adsl2pSpeed = '9500 - 12500';

function test() {
 alert(adsl2pSpeed);
 if (!adsl2pSpeed) {
   alert(adsl2pSpeed);
   var adsl2pSpeed = 'Unknown';
 }
 var speed = document.getElementById("PredictedSpeed");
 speed.innerHTML = adsl2pSpeed + " b/s";
}

// some code runs ...  

test();
```

then the declaration of `adsl2pSpeed` inside the `if`-statement is "hoisted" to the top of the function, so that the function actually is interpreted like this:

```
function test() {
 var adsl2pSpeed;  // declaration hoisted to the top, shadows the global var
 alert(adsl2pSpeed);
 if (!adsl2pSpeed) {
   alert(adsl2pSpeed);
   adsl2pSpeed = 'Unknown';   // assignment to local var
 }
 var speed = document.getElementById("PredictedSpeed");
 speed.innerHTML = adsl2pSpeed + " b/s";
}
```

This article explains it: http://bustingseams.blogspot.com/2009/08/another-javascript-pitfall-hoisting.html